# Where in the Protect America Act is it stated that the NSA can monitor all electronic communication?

Tags: united-states, internet, software, international, bills

There is a statement that I have heard floating around regarding the Protect America Act (2007) https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/110/s1927/text and the powers it grants to the NSA (National Security Agency)

I have heard it stated that the act allows the NSA to, "monitor all electronic communication," even domestically, assuming that the domestic individual is, "communicating with foreigners who are the targets of a U.S. terrorism investigation."

After reading the Act however, I have found nothing that indicates this. Is the claim false, or am I just missing something?